# Auto-complete dependency version in properties

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, intellij-idea

In my pom, I have extracted the version of a dependency as a property like this:

```
<properties>
  <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However, by doing that, I lose the auto-completion that I would get if I entered the version directly in the dependency group.

**Is there a trick to get auto-completion of the version when using a property like above?**

Note: I'm equally interested in answers for Netbeans and Intellij.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way in IntelliJ, is to click inside the `<dependencies></dependencies>`, and, just type `dep` like this:

```
<dependencies>
    dep
</dependencies>
```

then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>.  You will then see something like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId></groupId>
        <artifactId></artifactId>
        <version></version>
</dependency>
```

with the cursor inside of the `artifactId` tab.  Start typing your artifact name, e.g. `slf`, and the list of choices will narrow down until you see the one you want. Select that, and it will fill in the artifactId, and move the cursor to `groupId`.  It will probably be the one you want, so just hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Then the cursor will move to the `version` tag, and show a list of available version numbers. Select the version number and it will end up looking something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.18</version>
</dependency>
```

I want the version number to be specified in `dependencyManagement,dependencies`, not `build,dependencies` so I tell IntelliJ to extract what it can into dependencyManagement, by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, which leaves only the group and artifact in build dependencies, and puts all 3 values in dependencyManagement dependencies.

Then, in dependencyManagement dependencies, I click on the version number and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to replace the version number with a property.

**Important** - use the name it suggests for the property name.  If you do, then you will be able to use

```
mvn versions:display-property-updates
```

which will look in your repositories for newer versions and list them.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE can't auto complete a property because it doesn't know the context in which the property is used. A property value could be used in various locations in the POM file for different dependencies.

If you want to keep auto-complete you can't have a property

EDIT: Tried in NetBeans and IntelliJ and you can't autocomplete a property in a POM file.

Answer (score 1):

On IntelliJ, first create your dependency with the version for auto completion

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Then underline the version and use the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+v`

Or with your mouse `Right Click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Property`

Comment: You can then autocomplete that property and it will show you versions of slf4j-api available?

Comment: Nope, but you can do the exact same thing when you want to upgrade ;)